# How can I declare current page in vba macros word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I want to know how to declare between current page, next page and a counter.

I have this code:

```
Dim docNew As Document
With ActiveDocument
Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToNext)

Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
'Create a new document and adds a shape
```

I'm trying to change "`wdGoToNext`" to "`CurrentPage`" (`Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=ActualPage)`), but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me? The question is simple, but I have a hard time understanding it.

Comment: https://www.codevba.com/Word/Range/GoTo.htm#.Y2l4h3bP2Uk

Comment: This would likely be better posted in Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word